# heigthmaps slow down simulation

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Im working on a proyect, and Im using heigthmaps models. When I add them to the simulatoin, Gazebo slow down a lot and even freezes. I have also realized that , the higher I set the max heigth in the sdf file , the slower the simulation is. Does anyone know why  this happends?Is there any way to solve it? Im using gazebo 7 in Ubuntu 16.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19538/heigthmaps-slow-down-simulation/) by [Mansan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4773/mansan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 68 on 2018-05-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

1. Can you try running `gzserver` without `gzclient`, does the problem still happen?  You can monitor the real time factor with the command `gz stats`
2. If the problem doesn't happen, you can try setting the level of detail for heightmaps for `gzclient` by adding this to `~/gui.ini`:

   ```
    [heightmap]
    lod=3
   ```
3. You could also try reducing the definition of your heightmap

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mansan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4773/mansan/) on 2018-06-14**:
Thanks!This helped me a lot! Running gzserver doesn't slow down the simulation, and most of the time I dont need to use the client, so it is at least a partial solution.